# Ajax calendar is not working in Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: c#

Ajax Calendar is not working in the Firefox and chrome...I have used this coding...Or is there any calendar which works in all the browser..if there means say?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Shift.ascx.cs"
Inherits="UserControl_ManageCalenderShift" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Alpha" Namespace="LMS" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<form id="Test" runat="server">
    <table id="swipe" cellpadding="0" runat="server" cellspacing="2" class="table-border"
        align="center" width="990">
        <tr class="widget-text">
            <td class="heading-row">
                <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" Text="Manage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="widget-bg2">
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/clock_add.png" />
                            <cc1:CalendarExtender CssClass="cal_Theme1" ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"
                                PopupButtonID="Image1" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                            </cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_date" runat="server" CssClass="text_box"
                 ontextchanged="txt_date_TextChanged" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txt_date_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                          Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txt_date" />
```

You have to create one script manager for the calender extender

Comment: after <form id="form1" runat="server"> u have to take one script manager..script manager can be avilable in the toolbox.....just apply it and check it out it may help u.......

Comment: Whether  Form Should be given necessary?

Comment: k..take one text bob first........then give it calender extender....add a script manager after <form id="form1" runat="server">

Comment: In my Master Page I Have the Script Manger In case what to do.

Comment: no i dont think so there is...just remove it........take new script manager from the toolbox

Comment: my code.......i have use this code in project for calnder....it display in fire fox.....

Comment: i dont think so there is script manager in master pager........u use master page for wich purpouse?.......master page min u use it for comon layout page ya as master

Comment: give me your coding watever in your master page